# SQLITE3 - How to auto detect the table in my database based on the data entered?

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5

I am setting up a function to add a new row of data that will be entered in to my database on one of the 8 "material tables".

```
def Add_New(self):
    pref = self.adding.addcode_text.text()
    grade = self.adding.addgrade_text.text()
    desc = self.adding.adddesc_text.text()
    supp = self.adding.addsupp_text.text()
    try:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO ***auto detected table*** (prefix,grade,desc1,supplier)VALUES(?,?,?,?)',(pref,grade,desc,supp))
        conn.commit()
        print('DONE')
        self.Load_***Auto detected***Db()
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
```

I am unsure of how to make it auto detect which table to put the new row of data in based on the users entry of 'Pref'. Pref is a 3 digit code that is unique. each table has a range of values allocated....i.e table 1 the 3 digit codes all begin with a '1'. table 2 the 3 digit codes all begin with a '2' etc.

Do i need an if statement to handle this? if the 1st digit is a 1 then select table 1 in the database to store it? Or can i point it to the correct table by having it identify the currentwidget and what that is pointing to?

I will assign the function to a pushbutton to trigger the event.

Apologies for the novice questions its my first week of programming and could really use any help you folks can offer.

material database return to tablewidgets:

[image: material database return to tablewidgets]

```
import sqlite3
from mcnc import Ui_MainWindow
import mcnclogo_rc
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow,QTableWidgetItem
import sys

conn = sqlite3.connect('codes.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('')

class MainApp(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainApp,self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.Load_StainlessDb()
        self.Load_SteelDb()
        self.Load_aluminiumDb()
        self.Load_plasticDb()
        self.Load_miscDb()
        self.Load_duplexDb()
        self.Load_consumablesDb()
        self.Load_freeIssueDb()

    def Load_StainlessDb(self):
        content = 'SELECT * FROM stainless'
        res = conn.execute(content)
        for row_index, row_data in enumerate(res):
            self.tableWidget_9.insertRow(row_index)
            for column_index, column_data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget_9.setItem(row_index, column_index,         
                QTableWidgetItem(str(column_data)))
        conn.close
        return

    def Load_SteelDb(self):
        content = 'SELECT * FROM steel'
        res = conn.execute(content)
        for row_index, row_data in enumerate(res):
            self.tableWidget_2.insertRow(row_index)
            for column_index, column_data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget_2.setItem(row_index, column_index,     
                QTableWidgetItem(str(column_data)))
        conn.close
        return

    def Load_aluminiumDb(self):
        content = 'SELECT * FROM aluminium'
        res = conn.execute(content)
        for row_index, row_data in enumerate(res):
            self.tableWidget_3.insertRow(row_index)
            for column_index, column_data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget_3.setItem(row_index, column_index,     
                QTableWidgetItem(str(column_data)))
        conn.close
        return

    def Load_plasticDb(self):
        content = 'SELECT * FROM plastic'
        res = conn.execute(content)
        for row_index, row_data in enumerate(res):
            self.tableWidget_4.insertRow(row_index)
            for column_index, column_data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget_4.setItem(row_index, column_index, 
                QTableWidgetItem(str(column_data)))
        conn.close
        return

    def Load_miscDb(self):
        content = 'SELECT * FROM misc'
        res = conn.execute(content)
        for row_index, row_data in enumerate(res):
            self.tableWidget_5.insertRow(row_index)
            for column_index, column_data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget_5.setItem(row_index, column_index, 
                QTableWidgetItem(str(column_data)))
        conn.close
        return

    def Load_duplexDb(self):
        content = 'SELECT * FROM duplex'
        res = conn.execute(content)
        for row_index, row_data in enumerate(res):
            self.tableWidget_6.insertRow(row_index)
            for column_index, column_data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget_6.setItem(row_index, column_index,     
                QTableWidgetItem(str(column_data)))
        conn.close
        return

    def Load_consumablesDb(self):
        content = 'SELECT * FROM consumables'
        res = conn.execute(content)
        for row_index, row_data in enumerate(res):
            self.tableWidget_7.insertRow(row_index)
            for column_index, column_data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget_7.setItem(row_index, column_index, 
                QTableWidgetItem(str(column_data)))
        conn.close
        return

    def Load_freeIssueDb(self):
        content = 'SELECT * FROM freeIssue'
        res = conn.execute(content)
        for row_index, row_data in enumerate(res):
            self.tableWidget_8.insertRow(row_index)
            for column_index, column_data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget_8.setItem(row_index, column_index, 
                QTableWidgetItem(str(column_data)))
        conn.close
        return

    def Add_New(self):
        pref = self.adding.addcode_text.text()
        grade = self.adding.addgrade_text.text()
        desc = self.adding.adddesc_text.text()
        supp = self.adding.addsupp_text.text()
        try:
            c.execute('INSERT INTO t     
            (prefix,grade,desc1,supplier)VALUES(?,?,?,?)', 
            (pref,grade,desc,supp))
            conn.commit()
            print('DONE')
            self.Load_freeIssueDb()
        except Exception as error:
        print(error)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainApp()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the code in place with the necessary changes to table names...

```
def Add_New(self):
    pref = self.adding.addcode_text.text()
    grade = self.adding.addgrade_text.text()
    desc = self.adding.adddesc_text.text()
    supp = self.adding.addsupp_text.text()
    tables = {"1": "Stainless", "2": "Steel", "3": "Aluminium", "4": 
    "Plastic", "5": "misc", "6": "duplex", "8": "consumables", "9": 
    "freeIssue" }
    table = tables[pref[0]]
try:
    c.execute('INSERT INTO ' + table + ' 
    (prefix,grade,desc1,supplier)VALUES(?,?,?,?)',(pref,grade,desc,supp))
    conn.commit()
    print('DONE')
    getattr(self, 'Load_' + table + 'Db')()
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```

Also here is the buttonWidget connect statement...

```
self.ui = MainApp()
    self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.Add_New)
    self.show
```

This is how it appears in Visual Studio for me...

[Code as it appears in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OXGz.png)

Comment: Is it always just the first digit that determines which table?

Comment: Yes the 1st digit doesnt change in the table...its like 101-199 is table 1, 201-299 is table 2 etc. however the range is not defined anywhere in my code or the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just the first digit that determines the table, you can use a dictionary to map the digit to table names.

When calling the `Load_XXXDb()` method, you can use `getattr()` to get the attribute dynamically.

```
def Add_New(self):
    pref = self.adding.addcode_text.text()
    grade = self.adding.addgrade_text.text()
    desc = self.adding.adddesc_text.text()
    supp = self.adding.addsupp_text.text()
    tables = {"1": "Stainless", "2": "Steel", "3": "Aluminum", ...}
    table = tables[pref[0]]
    try:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO ' + table + ' (prefix,grade,desc1,supplier)VALUES(?,?,?,?)',(pref,grade,desc,supp))
        conn.commit()
        print('DONE')
        getattr(self, 'Load_' + table + 'Db')()
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
```